# Datadog not picking up custom metrics changes

Tags: kotlin, kubernetes, datadog, spinnaker

I have a kotlin api, the deployment for which takes via spinnaker to kubernetes. I made some change in code for custom metric inclusion in datadog for the app, when I made 1st change and deployed the code worked fine however after that I made some other changes and I could not see data in datadog so I reverted the changes and ensured multiple times that the code I am trying to deploy is same as the initial version I tired to deploy however now the same code is not pushing data in datadog, what can be the cause of this and how to debug? Have tried making changes in other branches/ repo but have not been able to figure out, this inconsistency is only happening for custom metrics.